# Is there a way to set the default namespace with Savon::Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, savon

Savon is stubborn in generating SOAP envelopes from WSDL's. It does it improperly and I see no way to fix it. It also takes the liberty of inserting the `wsdl:` namespace on everything for whatever reason.

The request I am building uses the `tns:` namespace. I'd love to be able to use Savon::Model, but right now I have to do:

```
client.request :tns, :function_name do
  soap.body = { params }
end
```

Instead of something like:

```
super(params)
```

Making the request block in every function is tedious, and I have to define the function name every time instead of Savon automatically calling the correct function like what would happen in the ideal case. Right now my functions are looking like

```
def foo
  client.request :tns, :foo do
  ...
end
```

Having to say "foo" twice seems ridiculous. Is there a way to set the default namespace for every request in a class that extends Savon::Model?

Answer (score 1):

```
client = Savon.client do
  wsdl "blah blah"
  element_form_default :qualified
  namespace_identifier :tem
  env_namespace :soapenv
end
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer so the future questioners can apply it to their problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your questions. I assume you are asking how to set the default namespace and wrap the request body in a function, so you don't need to write the request body every time. This code works for me, but I removed some irrelevant parts

```
class ExampleWS
  EXAMPLE_WS_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE = "urn:example:request:1.0.0"
  ......
  def getStockPrice( locale, stockId )
    response = $client.request :get_stock_price do
    soap.input = [
      "ns1:getStockPrice",
      {
        "xmlns:ns1" => EXAMPLE_WS_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE #set default namespace here
      }
    ]
    soap.body = {
      "locale" => locale,
      "stockId" => stockId
    }
    end
  end
  ......
end
......
# call the function
getStockPrice("en_US", 123 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. It uses Savon 2, though:

```
class Soapservice
  extend Savon::Model

  client wsdl: "http://example.com?wsdl", env_namespace: :tns, 

  operations :get_resource, :put_resource

  def :get_resource(id)
    super(message: { id: id })
  end
end

service = Soapservice.new
response = service.get_resource(1) #overwriting get_resource
# or
response = service.put_resource(message: { username: "luke", secret: "secret" })
```

(My example builds on the one from the official [savon homepage](http://savonrb.com/version2.html#model))